# Firebase Web FCM messages (messaging/use-public-key-before-get-token)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Iam getting the following error when I signout and signin into my application.

```
code: "messaging/use-public-key-before-get-token",
message: "Messaging: Error (messaging/use-public-key-before-get-token)."
```

Each time I signin to my application Iam calling `messaging.requestPermission()` and then `messaging.getToken()` . For the first time the application is loding fine , but if I logout and login again , (triggering the `permission` and `getToken` again) , returning the above error.

Iam using the following code :

```
   requestPermission() {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.usePublicVapidKey(this.PUBLIC_VPA);

        messaging.requestPermission().then(() => {
            console.log('Notification permission granted.');

            // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
            // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
            messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
                if (currentToken) {
                    console.log(currentToken, 'currentToken');
                    this.sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                } else {
                    console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
                    this.generateRefreshToken();
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
            });

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });

}
```

Any suggestions will be helpful, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ran into your question when I had the same issue but fixed it by updating the Firebase instance. For most cases, you'll only want a single FB instance but you get conflicts if you don't manage how your app uses Firebase carefully.

When you're logged in and then trying to log out/in again, errors will get thrown since you may be trying to use FB messaging services that has conflicting information when trying to retrieve the instance.

I'm using Redux and actually update the FB instance `firebase.initializeApp({config})` via a listener that's synced up with my store.

Hope you were able to resolve as well.

Comment: To clarify, you just have to update your firebase scripts. I updated mine from 5.4.0 to 6.0.2 and this issue went away.